# Calculating finite integrals with variable bounds

Tags: r, math, integral

I have the following integral:

[image]

the problem is, that the upper bound is not a specific number but a variable t. Is there any way or library in R that would give me the result using variable t?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for the `integrate` function - if that doesn't do what you need, you may need to expand your question with more information.

Comment: @Dubukay function integrate doesn't work correctly with t as upper bound. It wants a specific number ,like 1 and 2.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to loop over the upper bounds you're providing? This code works with t as a variable: `t <- 5` `integrate(function(x)x^2, lower = 0, upper = t)`

Comment: @Dubukay the T stays fixed. I just need it integrated, any calculation is yet to be done.

Comment: Are you looking for the indefinite integral, aka antiderivative? In a [wolfram-alpha style](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2) interpreter that returns a function, where that function is the indefinite integral of your input function?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that will evaluate the integral from `0` to the input argument:

```
c <- 2
i <- 3

fInt <- function(tt) integrate(function(t) (c*t)^i*exp(-c*t), 0, tt)
fInt2 <- function(tt) integrate(function(t) t^i*exp(-t)/c, 0, tt*c) # equivalent

fInt(4)
#> 2.87286 with absolute error < 6.5e-12
fInt2(4)
#> 2.87286 with absolute error < 6.5e-12
```